# How to change network interfaces' priority

Tags: networking, ifconfig

I have 3 network interfaces: `lo`, `new0` and `new1`. I use `new1` to access the internet.

My computer went nuts a few days ago and began to try to access the internet on `lo`. Doing `ifconfig lo down` causes packets to go via `new0`. But I want it to use `new1`.

I can use `ssh`, download torrents and use other protocols, but http and https are not working; I just get instant "Server not found" without loading time in browser.

How can have the system prefer `new1` over `new0` and `lo`?

I'm not able to change my `metric`, both `new1` and `new0` are stuck at 1.

Comment: Best solution is here: https://superuser.com/q/331720/600860

Answer (score 5):

Prioritising interfaces for general traffic is done by **manipulating the routing metrics**.

Each route has associated parameters such as hop-counts and bandwidths. See `netstat -nr` and the "`metric`" option in the man-page for `route` command.

For very simple control of metric use **ifmetric** tool:

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install ifmetric
```

Once installed use it to change metric value for interface,
 refer this http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/vivid/man8/ifmetric.8.html

Comment: This worked for on Ubuntu 16.04, but it took me some time to figure out exact commands.
The first thing to do is finding interface you want to update and metric value to set. To do so run `route` command and note `Iface` and `Metric` column values. (netstat doesn't show metric value, metric from ifconfig is not what you are looking for).
To de-prioritize interface (e.g. ens33) you need, pick metric value a bit larger than other interfaces. Let's say it is 110. Now run ifmetric as follows:
`sudo ifmetric ens33 110`

Answer (score 4):

Metric can change on several place.
Best working for me is configuration in `etc/network/interface`

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
auto new0
iface new0 inet static
    address xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
    netmask xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
    up route add default gw aaa.aaa.aaa.aaa metric 10
    down route del default gw aaa.aaa.aaa.aaa

auto new1
iface new1 inet static
    address yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy
    netmask yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy
    up route add default gw bbb.bbb.bbb.bbb
    down route del default gw bbb.bbb.bbb.bbb
```

On this way when interface `new0` go up will bring route to gateway `aaa.aaa.aaa.aaa` with metric 10. Interface `new1` bring up route to `bbb.bbb.bbb.bbb` with lower metric and traffic will be routed on that interface.

If you do `sudo ifdown new1` on unplug cable from card route will be deleted and route to `aaa.aaa.aaa.aaa` will be new best route for traffic.

When again brin int `new1` up route will again be added and `bbb.bbb.bbb.bbb` will again be your best route.

Edit 1

Route priority is not the same like route based on destination port.

But I give you example to route traffic for ssh, `port 22` and you can implement for port you need for

Let’s start from the iptable. Here we shall take `ssh` as the service for routing. Use `mangle` table of iptable for modifying the `ssh` packets.

```
  sudo iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT -p tcp –dport 22 -j MARK –set-mark 0×1
```

We are marking all packets with destination port `22` as ’0×1′ .

Now save and restart `iptables`.

```
service iptables save
service iptables restart
```

To delete this entry from `iptables` we can use `-D` instead of `-A`.

Next, create a new IP route table in `/etc/iproute2/rt_table` by just giving an entry

```
100 sshtable
```

Write rule for `ssh` packets.

```
ip rule add fwmark 0×1 lookup sshtable
```

Add route at new table `sshtable`. Here we shall use ’192.168.1.1′ as the gateway for `ssh`. Address ’192.168.1.1′, in this example will be gateway address for `new2` All other traffic will go through the
default gateway aka `new1`, which can be seen by IP route show command.

We copy all entries except default gateway entry from main table.

```
 sudo ip route show table main | grep -Ev ^default | while read ROUTE ; do ip route add table sshtable $ROUTE; done
```

Add default gateway entry for `ssh` packets to table `sshtable`

```
  sudo ip route add default via 192.168.1.1 table sshtable
```

Use `ip route show table sshtable` to show all routes at `sshtable`.

That’s it..we have done it!!!

Repeat everything for `imap` on port `465` or `hhtp` on port `80` or `https` on port `443` ...

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not sure my problem is that simple. Strangely i can access `ssh` and other protocols. (but NOT `http` or `https`) Is there some "special" protocol routing ?

Comment: You have My `Edit 1` in answer for routing based on destination port.